# About bug details

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java. While running the java application I got below mentioned bug.  Why has this bug occured?

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (exceptions.cpp:367), pid=2552, tid=2532
#  Error: ExceptionMark destructor expects no pending exceptions
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b22 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86)
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00385800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=2532, stack(0x00390000,0x003e0000)]

Stack: [0x00390000,0x003e0000]
[error occurred during error reporting (printing stack bounds), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x029c6000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2648, stack(0x02c70000,0x02cc0000)]
  0x029b8000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2876, stack(0x02c20000,0x02c70000)]
  0x029b6c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1464, stack(0x02bd0000,0x02c20000)]
  0x029b6000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1248, stack(0x02b80000,0x02bd0000)]
  0x029b1800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4084, stack(0x02b30000,0x02b80000)]
  0x029ad400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4068, stack(0x02ae0000,0x02b30000)]
=>0x00385800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=2532, stack(0x00390000,0x003e0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x029ac000 VMThread [stack: 0x02a90000,0x02ae0000] [id=4064]
  0x029e1400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02cc0000,0x02d10000] [id=2656]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 960K, used 271K [0x228d0000, 0x229d0000, 0x22db0000)
  eden space 896K,  30% used [0x228d0000, 0x22913ea8, 0x229b0000)
  from space 64K,   0% used [0x229b0000, 0x229b0000, 0x229c0000)
  to   space 64K,   0% used [0x229c0000, 0x229c0000, 0x229d0000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 0K [0x22db0000, 0x231b0000, 0x268d0000)
   the space 4096K,   0% used [0x22db0000, 0x22db0000, 0x22db0200, 0x231b0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 23K [0x268d0000, 0x274d0000, 0x2a8d0000)
   the space 12288K,   0% used [0x268d0000, 0x268d5cd0, 0x268d5e00, 0x274d0000)
    ro space 8192K,  62% used [0x2a8d0000, 0x2add2a60, 0x2add2c00, 0x2b0d0000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x2b0d0000, 0x2b7186e0, 0x2b718800, 0x2bcd0000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00423000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_06\bin\javaw.exe
0x77cc0000 - 0x77d75000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x77e60000 - 0x77f50000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77f50000 - 0x77feb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77340000 - 0x773d1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77d80000 - 0x77e11000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x773e0000 - 0x77425000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_06\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d7c0000 - 0x6da10000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_06\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d270000 - 0x6d278000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_06\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d770000 - 0x6d77c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_06\bin\verify.dll
0x6d310000 - 0x6d32f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_06\bin\java.dll
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_06\bin\zip.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: com.screen.Splash
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin;.;
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin;.;
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.6.0_07/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.6.0_07/bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools\WinNT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin;.;
USERNAME=sun
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 8 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 2, v.2096

CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 8 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse

Memory: 4k page, physical 261616k(53616k free), swap 633092k(297116k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b22) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_06-b02), built on Mar 25 2008 01:22:05 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1

time: Tue Feb 10 16:59:05 2009
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: What program are you trying to run? what is the source code?

Answer (score 2):

You are also running jre1.6.0_07 - but your classpath and java_home are pointing to

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin;.;
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin;.;

This mix of paths might be causing some problems for the runtime.

I'd suggest uninstalling all versions of java (it appears you have several) and upgrading to the latest release. And then making sure all your variables point to that single release.

Comment: _07 is on the path but I believe Q'er is running _06. Check out the vm info on the third-last line.

Comment: He should update anyway, it seems like he's using the beta of _06.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running some web application into IE 7? I have seen few similar crashes posted over the internet. If thats the case, try to use some other browser.

Possible take ups can be,

- Try other browser then IE, if you are running some application under IE
- Try de-install JRE/JDK, and install a new from the scratch. **Choose a released version, not beta**. And please **don't do it under program files** this time, **choose a path without spaces**. Although, **spaces can't be the reason of the crash**

The crash should not happen after this. And if it persist, report it as suggested in the error message.

Comment: i'm running simple java apllicaion under eclipse-java-ganymede-SR1-win32 uising jre1.6.0_06

Comment: You are running beta, I believe. Just try to install a released version preferably latest JRE 6 Update 12, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Internal errors should always be submitted to Sun. They shouldn't happen no matter how bad your code is. Sun's web page for submission is [here](http://bugs.sun.com/) or [here](http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp).

Just make sure it's not already reported and that you can reproduce it easily.

Comment: He is running beta, Pax, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this problem very now and then or a lot of times then you can log a bug to sun. Also I would suggest  you to upgrade your JVM version if its possible as that is what sun will suggest at first place.